# Does authorization in ASP.NET only means restricting access to pages and directories

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I have been reading a lot about asp.net membership and roles for the past couple of days and trying implement it in my project using form based authentication. I tried out most of the samples that I found on the internet from managing user/roles using WSAT to managing urser/roles/access rules in code. No doubt it provides great functionality with little effort on developer's end but some how I have developed the feeling that authorization in asp.net only provides a way to restrict access to pages and directories. What if I have a page which can be accessed by all users and based on the user role, the page offer different functionality to the user (common scenario - like SO is using). Though we can check `Roles.IsUserInRole(role)` in our code and customize the page for different roles but then again we can code the functionality to create more roles and enable users (Admins) to create more. And once the application is up and running, users (admins) create new roles, how do we take care of such roles in our pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.  You are right that Roles.IsUserInRole(role) can be used to customize pages for different roles.  So it's not all about restricting access to pages and directories.

If you're asking how to accommodate new roles created by user administrators, and how to have the pages adapt to these new roles ... well, I think the term for what you're talking about is "dynamic roles".  If you want a system where the users decide who can access what and create new roles with different access, you need a system that supports dynamic roles.

I've seen a lot of attempts to hand-code such a system, and I have yet to personally see one that was done well.  Some systems that do exactly that and do it well are commercial CMS (content management systems).  If you have an actual need for such a system, you might want to look at some of them.

ASP.NET's built-in role management is neat stuff, but it's really meant for a static role situation, where there are (say) "Payables Clerks", "Receivables Clerks" and "Managers" and, while people may change roles, the roles themselves and what people in them need to do don't change much.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, that cleared few things.. So what I take from what you said is that enabling end users to create roles and define access rules would not be a good practice, rather roles should be hard coded at development stage if we use asp.net membership and roles

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad security practice.  That's not something I'm qualified to pass judgment on:  I'm not a security expert.  (Although I'd recommend that you do research the question.)  But I can say with confidence that ASP.NET role management is not the tool you need if your heart is set on dynamic roles.

Answer (score 0):

RE: Ann L's comment  on her own answer (I can't write a comment because I don't have enough reputation points yet).

If an administrator of the application is able to create new roles, it simply means that authenticated (!) users within those roles have rights to do more or other things (depending on those roles).

I don't think that letting users (admins) create roles dynamically would be a bad security practice. Bad security practices are, in my opinion, those that enable malevolent users to cause damage, steal data or hijack the application. Those bad practices enable people to be authenticated in a way that you wouldn't want them to be.